# Partial Derivatives - Find the tangent line

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

So I'm trying to find the tangent line of the form $(ax + by = c)$ to the level curve at point $(1,1)$ of $$f(x,y) = 3x^2y^2+2x^2-3x+2y^2$$

I'm not quite sure how to go about this.
If I take both derivatives ($f_x$ and $f_y$) and plug in the points individually it doesn't really make much sense, I was hinted towards trying implicit differentiation but that also seems a bit weird. Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no tangent line for functions of two variables the graph of this function lives in three dimensions so the equation of a line isn't $ax+by=c$. Where did you get this question? Are they asking for a tangent plane? Or perhaps a normal line?

Comment: @ndhanson3 they are asking for a tangent line to the level curve at $(1,1)$

Comment: Be sure to add that information to the question!

Comment: Whoops, my bad, will edit now!

Comment: The level curve is always perpendicular to the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the gradient? I was told implicit differentiation is supposed to work @Karl

Comment: If you try both approaches you'll see that they're essentially doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

A level curve of a surface is a curve where $f(x,y)$ is constant. Since we want the level curve that contains $(1,1)$, we plug in this point to get $f(1,1)=4$. So we want to find the line tangent to $$4=3x^2y^2+2x^2-3x+2y^2$$ through the point $(1,1)$. Now, you should use implicit differentiation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

If you are looking to use the partial derivatives instead of the implicit differentiation, for a level curve $F(x,y)=k$, that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-F_x}{F_y}.$$

Either way, once you have $\frac{dy}{dx}$, use point-slope form $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ to get the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: Thanks!! Thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the equation of the curve is
$$3x^2y^2+2x^2-3x+2y^2=4$$ as $(1,1)$ falls on it.
D. w.r.t $x$:
$$6xy^2+6x^2yy'+4x-3+4yy'=0 \implies y'=\frac{3-4x-6xy^2}{6x^2y+4y}$$
$m=y'(1)=\frac{-7}{10}$
So the equation of the tangent on the curve at point $(1,1)$ is
$$y-1=\frac{-7}{10}(x-1)\implies 7x+10y=17.$$